# Not able to fetch public IP address of virtual machine scale set with Python SDK in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-python

I have a virtual machine scale set and I have two VMs attached to it and I want to fetch its public IP address with the Python SDK.

I am using this script to fetch IP configurations.

```
def get_vmss_vm_ips():

    # List all network interfaces of the VMSS instance
        vmss_nics = network_client.network_interfaces.list_virtual_machine_scale_set_network_interfaces(
            rg, vmscalesetname)

        niclist = [nic.serialize() for nic in vmss_nics]

        print "IP addresses in the given VM Scale Set:"

        for nic in niclist:
            ipconf = nic['properties']['ipConfigurations']
            print ipconf
```

This is my output:

```
{'id': u'/subscriptions/sub_id/resourceGroups/test/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/EchoServer/virtualMachines/2/networkInterfaces/test-vnet-nic01/ipConfigurations/test-vnet-nic01-defaultIpConfiguration', 'properties': {'subnet': {'id': u'/subscriptions/sub_id/resourceGroups/test/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/test-vnet/subnets/default'}, 'privateIPAddressVersion': u'IPv4', 'publicIPAddress': {'id': u'/subscriptions/sub_id/resourceGroups/test/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/EchoServer/virtualMachines/2/networkInterfaces/test-vnet-nic01/ipConfigurations/test-vnet-nic01-defaultIpConfiguration/publicIPAddresses/publicIp-test-vnet-nic01'}, 'privateIPAllocationMethod': u'Dynamic', 'primary': True, 'privateIPAddress': u'10.0.0.9'}, 'name': u'test-vnet-nic01-defaultIpConfiguration'}]
```

I can see `privateIPAddress`, but not `publicIPAddress`. How do I fetch the public IP address?

Comment: Do you have any update?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to the Azure scale set virtual machines' public IP address, please refer to the following script

1. Create a service principal and assign  `Contributor` role to the service principal

   ```
   az login
   az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "MyApp" --role contributor \
       --scopes /subscriptions/{SubID} --sdk-auth true
   ```
2. Code

   ```
   from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
   from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential

   client_id = "<sp appId>"
   secret = "<sp password>"
   tenant = "<sp tenant>"
   Subscription_ID = "<>"
   creds = ClientSecretCredential(
       client_id=client_id, client_secret=secret, tenant_id=tenant)

   network_client = NetworkManagementClient(creds, Subscription_ID)
   resource_group_name = "testVm_group"
   virtual_machine_scale_set_name = "testVm"
   results = network_client.public_ip_addresses.list_virtual_machine_scale_set_public_ip_addresses(
       resource_group_name, virtual_machine_scale_set_name)

   for result in results:
       print(result.id)
       print(result.ip_address)
   ```

   [image]